# How to type a function in Typescript that merges two key-value pairs

Tags: typescript

I merge two key-value pairs in an object and delete the original keys. I can't find the right type however. I've tried the following:

```
function mergeKeyValues<T, S>(
       obj: T, 
       key1: keyof T, 
       key2: keyof T, 
       newKey: string, 
       mergeFn: (a: T[keyof T], b: T[keyof T]) => S
    ): T & {[newKey: string]: S} {
       const mergedValue = mergeFn(obj[key1], obj[key2]);
       const out = {
          ...obj,
          [newKey]: mergedValue
       }
       delete out[key1];
       delete out[key2];
       return out;
}
```

However, if change the return type, for example, convert `{[newKey: string]: S}` to the incorrect `{[newKey2: string]: S}`, the error is not picked up. How can I show in the return type that the key has to be named `newKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mergeKeyValues<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends Exclude<keyof T, K1>, K3 extends PropertyKey, V>(
  obj: T,
  key1: K1,
  key2: K2,
  newKey: K3,
  mergeFn: (a: T[K1], b: T[K2]) => V
): Omit<T, K1 | K2> & Record<K3, V> {
  function omitDelete<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Omit<T, K> { for (let k of keys) delete obj[k]; return obj; }
  const mergedValue = mergeFn(obj[key1], obj[key2]);
  const copy = { ...obj }
  const extra = { [newKey]: mergedValue } as Record<K3, V>;
  let x = omitDelete(copy, [key1, key2])
  //  ^? Omit<T, K1 | K2>
  let y = Object.assign(x, extra)
  //  ^? Omit<T, K1 | K2> & Record<K3, V>
  return y;
}
```